# React/TypeScript: Destructured JS PropTypes not picked up as inferred TS types?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have a React project written in JavaScript, which I have started adding TypeScript to.

A JS component is giving me issues in TS because TS infers the types from the component's `PropTypes`, however the property I wish to add is *destructured* (and hence not in the `PropTypes`).

Let's imagine this **JavaScript** component:

```
function MyButton(props) {
  const { myOwnProp, children, ...rest } = props;

  /* Do something based on myOwnProp */

  return (
    <button {...rest}>{children}</button>
  );
}

MyButton.propTypes = {
  myOwnProp: PropTypes.any,
  children: PropTypes.any
};
```

Now in my **TypeScript** component, I wish to utilize `MyButton`:

```
function SomeComponent() {
  return (
    <MyButton onClick={() => {/* click event */}}>Click me</MyButton>
  );
}
```

However this gives me a type error because the properties that I am giving `MyButton` do not match its `PropTypes`. Clearly TypeScript cannot see that `onClick` is a valid property to provide (understandably).

- How can I provide these properties to the component?
- Is there something missing from the `PropTypes` which makes it technically invalid? Can "rest" props be defined?
- Must I migrate `MyButton` to TypeScript?

I can make changes to `MyButton` if necessary, but I would prefer a solution that doesn't require major rewrites because this may be present in several components.

Comment: You need to specify `...rest` for sure but I don't think `propTypes` supports it. Maybe add a custom validator? If you use TypeScript types instead of `propTypes` it's very easy to do.

Comment: I would probably be able to find a nice solution if `MyButton` was already written in TypeScript, but until it is migrated, I'm hoping for a solution that is backwards compatible to JavaScript. I know PropTypes can do custom validators, but can it calculate an unknown set of props?

Comment: If your only goal is to interface with TypeScript you can consider adding a `.d.ts` file that just contains the definition. This way you don't need to use `propTypes` and you don't need to modify your source file.

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around to avoid the issue with a minor tweak to the JavaScript component.

It appears that TypeScript is able to pick up props if they are immediately destructured in the function parameter list. This seems to include "rest" parameters.

"Re"-structuring the props seems to do the trick - possibly fooling TypeScript into not checking it very closely.

```
function MyButton({ ...props }) { // destructures the object back into an object
  const { myOwnProp, children, ...rest } = props;

  /* etc */
}
```

This may not be a *great* solution, but if the goal is just to allow TypeScript to tolerate ambiguous JS props, it may be acceptable.

Alternatively, as @Halcyon has mentioned, it may be better to provide a `.d.ts` file.